# Inconsistencies in While Loop Variables

Tags: vb.net, while-loop

I am in the midst of writing a simple encryptor/decryptor program and have run into a small issue. All the characters are being generated a different string of characters to uniquely identify them. These strings are meant to be all the same length but don't seem to be. The code in question: (Full code can be viewed [here](https://pastebin.com/mbvHiuTW))

```
Dim genLength As Integer = 0
Dim charNow As Integer = 0
Dim charGenned As String

Dim rndGend As Integer = 0

While genLength < enhancedMode
        fs.Write(arrayAll(charNow))
        Dim rndString As String = ""
        While rndGend < encLength
            Randomize()
            Dim genned As Integer = CInt(Math.Ceiling(Rnd() * 46)) + 1
            charGenned = arrayAll(genned)
            rndString = rndString + charGenned
            rndGend += 1
        End While
        fs.Write(rndString & vbNewLine)
        rndGend = 0
        charNow = charNow + 1
        genLength = genLength + 1
    End While
```

From what I can tell this should give me the result I am looking for, but the generated strings are not at all consistent in length. A sample of the output:

```
alh*ph)lufe$2fz!d7c0$qfd(ol6f173#
b^i24@^v0gx%01iqrpugg8)(mqsl8%
c1km5jnz0hti&u$#rqeh5ism31t^96^
dkx&6$ok!@u#*e^x6659jpvcnn258zpi
e%y1(y3%@w9kk9&h7d6gw)w72*3c9*d)j
fy#(i4yeg0%ltj@887!x4!e32^703e4l
gj$4#5&f!!zzdkvs)v@@94)*rcmroy
```

While the string after the letter A is 32 digits long, as is for B, and C, when you get to G, the string is only 29 characters long. It is most noticeable in the fact that the program only generates strings for characters up to numeral 5, then stops:

```
3%y1(y3%@w9kk9&h7d6gw)w72*3c9*d)j
4y#(i4yeg0%ltj@887!x4!e32^703e4l
5j$4#5&f!!zzdkvs)
```

What is going amiss here?

Comment: Have you debugged your code? You generally don't diagnose issues like this just from reading the code. You need to watch it as it executes.  You can then see exactly what it does so you can see exactly what it does wrong.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I've debugged every step of the way with msgboxes after every character is generated. Haven't found anything

Comment: You don't need any message boxes to debug. That's how people who don't know how to debug do it, including myself way back when. You need to learn how to use the debugger properly, i.e. set breakpoints, step through code line by line and examine application state using Watch and Immediate windows and the like. Before each step, you examine the state and make sure it is what it should be and determine what you expect to happen. You then step and see if that did actually happen. As soon as reality differs from expectation, you've found an issue. If it never does, your expectations are wrong.

Comment: If you expectations are wring then you need to ignore the code and go back to your algorithm and make sure that that works first. If it does, you then need to compare the code to see where it fails to implement the algorithm. If you don't actually have an algorithm then why should it be a surprise that the code doesn't work? If you don't know what the code is supposed to do then it likely won't do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tidied up a bit and changed to the Random class which I think is much easier to use. If you declaring an array in vb.net remember it is Dim variable(ubound) As Type. ubound stands for the Upper bound of the array, the highest index so an array with 47 elements would have indexes 0-46. The ubound would be 46 Dim variable(46) As String

```
Private r As New Random
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Button1.Enabled = False
    Dim arrayLetters() As String = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"}
    Dim arrayAll() As String = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")"}
    Dim encLength As Integer = 16
    If CheckBox2.Checked = True Then
        encLength = 32
    End If
    Dim enhancedMode As Integer = 26
    If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
        enhancedMode = 46
    End If
    Dim genLength As Integer = 0
    Dim charNow As Integer = 0
    Dim charGenned As String
    Dim rndGend As Integer = 0
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder
    While genLength < enhancedMode
        sb.Append(arrayAll(charNow))
        Dim rndString As String = ""
        While rndGend < encLength               
            Dim genned As Integer = r.Next(0, 46)
            charGenned = arrayAll(genned)
            rndString &= charGenned
            rndGend += 1
        End While
        sb.AppendLine(rndString)
        rndGend = 0
        charNow += 1
        genLength += 1
    End While
    Dim name As String
    If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
        name = "KeyGenned"
    Else
        name = TextBox1.Text
    End If
    Dim path As String = Application.StartupPath & "\" & name & ".txt"
    File.WriteAllText(path, sb.ToString)
    Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Also, the upper number of `Next` is exclusive, not inclusive.  Eric Lippert has been writing about the issues with `Random` recently.  See https://ericlippert.com/2019/01/31/fixing-random-part-1/

Comment: @AndrewMorton oops! Forgot to remove that. Answer edited. Thanks.

Comment: @Craig Good article. I addressed the first problem by declaring the Random class outside the method. The second problem can be fixed by reading the docs. The length of arrayAll is 46. So, r.Next(0,46) should produce indexes in the range 0-45 which is the desired result. Threading is not an issue in this code since it all runs on the UI thread. The deep dark internal workings of Random are not at issue either since this is not a complex Prob & Stat problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help Mary & @Craig The new code (with a little editing for other features), works perfectly. I did not think to use the StringBuilder.. I'll keep that in mind for the future.